# Apache2 not listening on SSL on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, apache2

Trying the configure SSL on Apache2 on Ubuntu server
installed Apache

```
sudo apt install apache2
```

Opened ufw firewall

```
sudo ufw allow 'Apache'
ufw allow https
```

Installed SSL files in /root/cert

```
 chmod 400 /root/cert/*
  chmod 500 /root/cert/
```

In /etc/apache2/sites-available found  two conf files:
domainname.conf and default-ssl.conf
DId not know which one to modify, so modified domainname.conf by adding following lines

```
 <VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /root/cert/ca-bundle.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /root/cert/Private.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /root/cert/certificate.crt
   </VirtualHost>

apachectl configtest
apachectl restart
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
systemctl enable apache2 --now 
netstat -ntlp |  grep 80
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      899/apache2  

netstat -ntlp |  grep 443

returns nothing
```

Added information - the website DNS resolution has not happened yet, because the nameserver is being changed. So I am checking on localhost.  localhost:80 works, localhost:443 does not work gives error: localhost refused to connect

Several questions:

1. have I switched files SSLCertificateFile SSLCertificateChainFile by mistake since I did not which one was which. Also it has comment statement -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- and -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
2. When I perform

   apache2ctl configtest
   it says
   AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
   Syntax OK

Is this a problem since nameserver is still pointing to old provider and I am in process of switching to new provider nameserver where the new website is running.

Can anyone help?

Comment: just a thought ... SSL certificates are for a domain ... `localhost` is not the domain in the certificate ... so ... perhaps that's why whatever you are using to test is refusing to connect? hmm, just read it again, port 443 isn't even open

Comment: Looks like you are missing the Listen directive for that port somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Apache process is not listening on port 443 you are missing the `Listen 443` directive in your configuration. It should be enabled by default if the `ssl` module is active, so make sure the module is loaded.

```
sudo a2enmod ssl
```

Comment: This command worked. It said Enabling module SSL. Later I ran 
netstat -ntlp |  grep 443
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      2897/apache2

Comment: If I run localHost:80 it correctly shows my website. However if I run localhost:443 it shows default ubuntu page. How to switch ubuntu page to my website for port 443?

Comment: Your 443 virtualhost is rather empty.  Copy the directives from the 80 virtualhost over.

Comment: 443 has all the directives from 80 and also inserted SSL commands, but still not working. Should I redirect port 80 to 443 or something?

Comment: How to redirect port 80 to 443

Comment: followed commands from url: https://o7planning.org/11363/redirect-port-80-443-on-ubuntu-using-iptables to forward from port 80 to 443. Now, If I do localhost:80 and look at chrome tools->developer Tools->network recording I see https urls being loaded. However if I do localhost:443 still shows ubuntu default page. Confused if it is working right or not. Also https://localhost gives error: This site can’t provide a secure connection

Comment: Also I have added 443 information to domainname.conf file. But I do see another file default-ssl.conf in the same directory. I have not edited this file. should I edit default-ssl.conf instead of domainname.conf. Please let me know how to fix this?

Comment: You should ask a new question for that.  Include your complete current config in it.

Comment: opened a new question

Answer (score 2):

Also (check other answers) you chould change the files in the config. This:

```
SSLCertificateFile /root/cert/ca-bundle.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /root/cert/Private.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /root/cert/certificate.crt
```

should be

```
SSLCertificateFile /root/cert/certificate.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /root/cert/Private.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /root/cert/ca-bundle.crt
```

Comment: I did swap the certs as suggested

Comment: @vrao, check also the answer of Gerald to enable the ssl

Comment: Your suggestion helped. But more importantly Gerlad's command helped me enable SSL, so I accepted his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Configuration from `/etc/apache2/sites-available` is not included in the `apache2.conf`, but configuration from `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`. Create a symlink using

```
sudo a2ensite domainname
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your domainname.conf file is not enabled.

Checkout the /etc/apache2/sites-enabled and to find out which configuration file is enabled.

Comment: it was domainname.conf